# Re-enable links disabled with disable_with

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

How can I manually re-enable links (not form elements) that get disabled with Rails' `disable_with` feature?

Answer (score 14):

The call to reenable links is slightly different than form elements. It actually binds a handler to the click event that stops anything else from happening. I was able to figure this out by [investigating how the jquery-ujs library](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L348-L355).

To reverse this effect, simply use the `enableElement` method on your jQuery object:

```
$.rails.enableElement($('a[data-disable-with]'));
```

With Turbolinks, it also helps to watch for the `'page:change'` event instead of `window.unload`:

```
$(document).on('page:change', function() {
   $.rails.enableElement($('a[data-disable-with]'));
});
```

Answer (score 9):

A solution I found [here](http://makandracards.com/makandra/3877-re-enable-submit-buttons-disabled-by-the-disabled_with-option):

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  $.rails.enableFormElements($($.rails.formSubmitSelector));
});
```

Comment: Yup, this works in Rails 3.2. Essentially, just pass a jQuery object or objects to `$.rails.enableFormElements` and it will re-enable it. In my case I passed the form I was submitting: `$.rails.enableFormElements( $( 'div.modal form' ) )`

Answer (score 5):

Rails has updated their javascript to no longer use jQuery.

You can now re-enable elements with the following (assuming you are still using jQuery):

```
var selectors = [Rails.linkDisableSelector, Rails.formEnableSelector].join(', ');
$(selectors).each(function() {
  Rails.enableElement(this);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey its quite simple you just need to find button and do

```
$button = $('#someId')
$.rails.enableElement($button)
$button.removeAttr('disabled')
```

Comment: This doesn't change the text (i.e. `value`) of the button back to what it was before submission.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @DGM solution I ended up with the following code:

```
$.rails.enableFormElements($disabled_button);
```

Where:

`$disabled_button` is the jQuery object for the button disabled by `data-disable-with` which could be selected like this:

```
$disabled_button = $('[data-disable-with]');
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I found this interesting work around (apparently the problem is only in FF)
set :autocomplete => 'off' and now it works.  Or one of the other answer might work as well.

ref: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/357

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery to remove the data-disable-with attribute that Rails adds to the button:
$('#disabledbutton').removeAttr('data-disable-with');

Comment: Ah, interesting. Looking for something to change it back to its original state. That doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: Like bevanb said. This does not change the element back to its original state.