# links with 'data-disable-with' are still disabled after pressing the back button on rails 5 (turbolinks & jquery ujs)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks

So I have a simple link:

`%td= link_to("#{fa("institution")} #{entity.short_name}".html_safe, entity_path(entity), class: "button", data: {disable_with: "<i class=\"fa fa-spin fa-circle-o-notch\"></i>".html_safe})`

When I press this link it shows a spinning icon and it redirects me to an other page. When I press the back button it still displays the spinning icon.

So I tried to fix this with multiple workarounds:

- [I read this issue](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/357) and added `autocomplete: "off"` to the link but
  it does not work.
- I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295187/re-enable-links-disabled-with-disable-with) on SO, discovered the `$.rails.enableElement()` function and tried on my browser console:
- `$.rails.enableElement($("a"))`
- `$.rails.enableElement($('[data-disable-with]'))`

That doesn't work either. Do you have any idea why any of these solutions isn't working? any suggestion?