# Re-enable submit after preventDefault

Tags: javascript

I have the following html form:

```
<form id="searchForm" action="/pages/index" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get">
   <input id="toValidate" type="text" name="search_form[mixed]"></div>
   <input id="toValidate" type="text" name="search_form[first_name]"></div>
   <select name="search_form[state]">
      <option selected="selected" value="All">All</option>
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
      <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
      <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" name="commit" value="SEARCH" id="submit" data-disable-with="SEARCH">
</form>
```

I want to make the user enter at least one input field. They way I thought to do that is with the following Javascript code:

```
function checkFields(form) {
    var inputs = form.find('toValidate').not('[type="submit"],[type="button"],[type="reset"]'); 

    var filled = inputs.filter(function(){
        return $.trim($(this).val()).length > 0;
    });
    
    if(filled.length === 0) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}

$(function(){
    $('#searchForm').on('submit',function(e){
        var oneFilled = checkFields($(this));
        if (oneFilled) {
            alert('At least ONE field filled!');
        } else {    
            e.preventDefault();
            if (confirm('NO FIELDS FILLED OUT!')){
                $('#submit').disabled = false;
            }else{
                $('#submit').disabled = false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The preventDefault() function disables the submit button but then I cannot re-enable the button again once I alerted the user. It's funny though, because when I paste the code `$('#submit').disabled = false;` on the console it re-enables the button. What should I do to re-enable the button within the JS code then?

From the eyes of a user:

When preventDefault(); it's called the button is disabled and then, once the user accepts the confirmation window she cannot submit the form again because the button is disabled. How can I make it so that the button becomes enabled once again after the confirmation window is accepted and the user can click on the 'SEARCH' button.

Thank you.

Comment: You can call “submit” on the form element which will submit the form.

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` just disables the default behavior of the event, in case of `submit` event, it will prevent browser window reload on form submission, it has nothing to do with disabling/enabling submit button. There are other issues in your code that you shold be addressed first. For example, you are using same `id` for both text `input` elements - id should be unique. Also inside the `checkFields` function, shouldn't `form.find('toValidate')` be `form.find('#toValidate')`?

Comment: Well, when preventDefault(); it's called the button is disabled and then, once the user accepts the confirmation window she cannot try to submit the form again because the button is disabled. How can I make it so that the button becomes enabled once again after the confirmation window is accepted. Thank you.

Comment: button itself is not disabled. You cannot click on any form element or anywhere else on the UI because of the `confirm` dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

- You don't need to disable the submit button at all. `e.preventDefault()` disables the form's submission, so when the fields are not filled, call it, and when they are filled, don't call it.
- Both your input fields have `id="toValidate"` and in the `checkFields` function, you're finding the input fields by `form.find('toValidate')` which is incorrect. You need to make the *classes* of those input fields `toValidate`, not their *IDs*, because IDs of two or more elements can not be the same.
- The selector `form.find('toValidate')` actually will work with neither ID nor class, because it's looking for elements with the **tag** `<toValidate>`. For finding elements with **IDs** of the text, the selector will be `form.find('#toValidate')` and for finding elements with **classes** of the text, it will be `form.find('.toValidate')`. We're going to use the latter in the code below.
- More a bad practice than an incorrect one, you are disabling the submit button. *Disabling the submit button does not mean that the user can't submit the form*. **The user can even then submit the form by pressing the enter key.**

In the below snippet, when your form is submitted, it checks the fields are filled or not. If they are not filled, it calls `e.preventDefault()` and if at least one is filled then it doesn't call `e.preventDefault()`, which will cause the form to submit (and a page reload).

```js
function checkFields(form) {
    var inputs = form.find('.toValidate').not('[type="submit"],[type="button"],[type="reset"]'); 

    var filled = inputs.filter(function(){
        return $.trim($(this).val()).length > 0;
    });
    
    if(filled.length === 0) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}

$('#searchForm').on('submit',function(e){
      var oneFilled = checkFields($(this));
      if (oneFilled) {
          alert('At least ONE field filled!');
      } else {    
          e.preventDefault();
          alert('NO FIELDS FILLED OUT!');
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="searchForm" action="/pages/index" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get">
   <input class="toValidate" type="text" name="search_form[mixed]"></div>
   <input class="toValidate" type="text" name="search_form[first_name]"></div>
   <select name="search_form[state]">
      <option selected="selected" value="All">All</option>
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
      <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
      <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" name="commit" value="SEARCH" id="submit" data-disable-with="SEARCH" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you detailed answer. However, the problem with the search button being disabled was not  because Javascript, but because Rails default configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42016113/rails-data-disable-with-re-enabling-button#answer-44025628
It is solved now. Thanks a lot for the corrections.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this if you want to destroy your custom submit handler :

`$('form').unbind("submit");`